# Why do random number generators cause problems when executed in parallel?

Tags: multithreading, performance, random, parallel-processing

I have an assignment and the following was mentioned:

> Parallelism adds further complications, as the random number
> generator function must behave correctly when two or more threads call
> it simultaneously, i.e., it must be thread-safe.

However, I can't understand why that is a problem in the first place. Random generators are usually called with a seed as a parameter and output a number by doing multiple operations on it, I understand that we need each thread to use a different seed but other than that where does the problem come from? I have realized that spawning and calling the random generator in a parallel region instead of a serial one also really worsens performance but I can't understand why this would happen as by the looks of it, the random number generator should run concurrently without any problems since they are no dependencies.

Any help in understand the theory behind this would be appreciated.

Comment: if 2 or more threads try to write back to the stored 'state' of the generator, race conditions can occur without locking

Comment: but as far as my basic understanding goes, this would explain a wrong result but not a slow performance (I know that adding locks would slow down the performance but I am just talking about the code in its initial state without fixing it)

Comment: In almost all cases, any time you have stored and shared written state between threads, you have to synchronise in order to maintain correctness.

Comment: Well I thought about performance as I am getting performance problems when calling a random generator in parallel, performance is around 2.5 times worse compared to calling it in serial and using its result in parallel (obviously that is not a good approach in terms of result as all threads would be using the same random number and I am doing a monte carlo method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from getting wrong values from the **race conditions** (pointed out by @MitchWheat), the code will be less efficient because of **cache-line sharing** between cores on mainstream x86 processors.

Here is an example of (pretty bad but simple) 32-bit random generator (written in C):

```c
uint32_t seed = 0xD1263AA2;

uint32_t customRandom() {
    uint32_t old = seed;
    seed = (uint32_t)(((uint64_t)seed * 0x2E094C40) >> 24);
    return old;
}

void generateValues(uint32_t* arr, size_t size) {
    for(size_t i=0 ; i<size ; ++i)
        arr[i] = customRandom();
}
```

If you run this example in sequential (see the result [here](https://godbolt.org/z/aW1znP4vd)), the state `seed` will likely be stored in the memory hierarchy using mainstream compilers (ie. GCC and Clang). This 32-bit block of memory will be read/written in the L1 cache which is very close to the core executing the code.

When you parallelize the loop naively, using for example `#pragma omp parallel for` in OpenMP, the state is read/written concurrently by multiple threads. There is a race condition: the state value `seed` can be read by multiple thread in parallel and be written in parallel. Consequently, the same value can be generated by multiple threads while the results are supposed to be random. Race condition are bad and must be fixed. You can fix that using a thread-local state here.

Assuming you do not fix the code because you want to understand the impact of the race condition on the resulting performance of this code, you should see a performance drop in parallel. The issue comes from the [cache coherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence) protocol used by x86 mainstream processors. Indeed, `seed` is shared between all the threads executed on each core so the processor will try to *synchronize* the cache of the core so they are kept coherent. This process is very expensive (much slower than reading/writing in the L1 cache). More specifically, when a thread on a given core write in `seed`, the processor invalidate the `seed` stored in all the other threads located in the caches of the other cores. Each thread must then fetch the updated `seed` (typically from the much slower L3 cache) when `seed` is read. You can find more information [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Well I am familiar with the cache coherency problem as I have studied false sharing using pthreads, I remember fixing this using padding, is there any method to fix this while using something like OpenMP assuming no changes are done to the random generator? or would someone just go for running the random generator in serial?

Comment: @Sergio No. AFAIK, OpenMP does not provide any way of controlling global variables (and I am not sure any library can, but the compiler could theoretically). The usual solution is to replace the hidden global state with a local variable provided to the generator. Global variable are generally bad for plenty of reason including performance (even in sequential code) and software engineering. You should avoid mutable global variables like the plague. An alternative solution is to put the variable `thread_local` in both C11 and C++11.